# Use PostgreSQLContainer with image on-the-fly in testcontainers

Tags: java, postgresql, testcontainers

### Goal

I want to use customized PostgreSQL image with locale support with test containers.

### On postgres side

I prepared `Dockerfile` as described in [postgres image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/):

> You can extend the Debian-based images with a simple Dockerfile to set a different  locale. The following example will set the default locale to de_DE.utf8:
>
> FROM postgres:14.3
>
> RUN localedef -i de_DE -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias de_DE.UTF-8
>
> ENV LANG de_DE.utf8

So essentially nothing changes in the way this image works, but has some more capabilities in terms of locale support.

### On testcontainers side

I wanted to use it as described in [testcontainers documentation](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/creating_images/):

> Simply pass a configured instance of ImageFromDockerfile as a constructor parameter to GenericContainer. Testcontainers will docker build a temporary container image, and will use it when creating the container.

```
public GenericContainer dslContainer = new GenericContainer(
new ImageFromDockerfile()
        .withFileFromString("folder/someFile.txt", "hello")
        .withFileFromClasspath("test.txt", "mappable-resource/test-resource.txt")
        .withFileFromClasspath("Dockerfile", "mappable-dockerfile/Dockerfile"))
```

### Problem

In examples above testcontainers uses `GenericContainer`. `GenericContainer` exposes constructor `public GenericContainer(final Future<String> image)`, what allows it to be used with `ImageFromDockerfile`. Sadly `PostgreSQLContainer` does not provide such constructor but **I still want to use this class because it has several internal setups** to support postgres well. There are two constructors in `PostgreSQLContainer` but they only accept image name.

Only solution I could think of was to essentially make a local copy of original `PostgreSQLContainer` and add missing constructor. That seems to work fine but it is a dirty hack for obvious reasons.

### Question

My question is: am I missing some other way to accomplish the task with tools testcontainers provide? Or is it an area of improvement to add such public constructor in testcontainers?

Comment: the solution is simple: build your own image and deploy it to registry/hub.

Comment: Yeah, right that is one way, but let's assume I would rather not to have to depend on any preexisting images somewhere in the infrastructure, but to be as self-contained as possible. This is why I go toward the 'on-the-fly' solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the solution would be:

```java
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;
import org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.LogMessageWaitStrategy;
import org.testcontainers.images.builder.ImageFromDockerfile;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;

import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.Duration;

import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.SECONDS;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // the most buggy part - need to investigate
        // how to work properly with ImageFromDockerfile
        URI path = Demo.class.getResource("/PostgreSQLde").toURI();
        ImageFromDockerfile image = new ImageFromDockerfile()
                .withDockerfile(Paths.get(path));
        DockerImageName imageName = DockerImageName.parse(image.get())
                .asCompatibleSubstituteFor(PostgreSQLContainer.IMAGE);
        new PostgreSQLContainer<>(imageName)
                .waitingFor(new LogMessageWaitStrategy()
                        // oops
                        .withRegEx(".*Datenbanksystem ist bereit, um Verbindungen anzunehmen.*\\s")
                        .withTimes(2)
                        .withStartupTimeout(Duration.of(60, SECONDS)))
                .start();
    }

}
```

Comment: There is a workaround suggested here: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/3184

I think that looks cleaner as you don't have to duplicate any of the logic for waiting for startup.